# Binding to TableView Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to use the following to bind to a TableView using Xamarin ios but i not having much luck As you can see I am using parse.com as me datalyer

```
  var query = from gaemPlayer in ParseObject.GetQuery ("players")
           select gaemPlayer;
  myPlayers.DataSource = query;
```

Where `myPlayers` is the table source Name i gave in iOS designer is c# I would normally have the `ToList` function to create a generic list is that not he case with Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Your source needs to be a class derived from UITableViewSource.  The source class will have methods to determine how many sections and rows per section are in a table, as well as method to actually build a UITableViewCell to display.  There are other methods you can override for additional functionality, but those are the bare minimum.

Note that the reason you can't just use a List as a Source is because Xamarin is modeling the Obj-C UITableView pattern.  An alternative for building simple tables is to use [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/).

```
public class MySource : UITableViewSource
{
  private List<item> data;

  public MySource(List<Item> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
  {
    return data.Count();
  }

  public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
  {
    return 1;
  }


  public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
  {
    // instantiate and return your UITableViewCell here
  }
```

Comment: i have a label in the cell and uimage view as well from what I see the getCell method would be where I woud access those propertyes would i be right

Comment: yes, you instantiate a cell and set it's properties in GetCell